# Cannot read property 'amphtml' of undefined for next AMP pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating APM pages on `Next.js 8.1` with `withAmp` function. and it's working fine,

But now I have updated `Next.js` version to canary version `8.1.1-canary.52`.
In this current canary version, `withAmp` is replaced with config export as given below.

```
export const config = {
    amp: 'hybrid'
};
```

But this time my project giving error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'amphtml' of undefined
>       at Html.render (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/.next/server/static/XYWItbKuNuzVScPFeX8wV/pages/_document.js:1049:49)
>       at c (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:35:231)
>       at Sa (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:36:1)
>       at a.render (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:467)
>       at a.read (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:41:58)
>       at renderToString (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:53:83)
>       at render (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/render.js:86:16)
>       at renderPage (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/node_modules/next-server/dist/server/render.js:236:20)
>       at _callee2$ (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/.next/server/static/XYWItbKuNuzVScPFeX8wV/pages/_document.js:994:24)
>       at tryCatch (/Users/ravi/Workspace/NextJs/cashify-react-site/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:45:40)

My `render` method of `_app.tsx` file is:

```
render(){
    const {Component, pageProps} = this.props;
    const {loaded} = this.state;

    let isAmp = false;
    if (this.props.router.query) {
        isAmp = this.props.router.query.amp === '1';
    }

    if (isAmp) {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
            <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Html>
        );
    } else {
        return (
            <Container>
                <ProgressBar loaded={loaded}/>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: can you make a reproduction in codesandbox or a git repo will be better

Comment: Facing same issue. But no solution seems to exist